# Weird planning time data dependency in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, execution-plan

We got a fairly large table holding session data in Postgres. Recently, we found that the planning time for the most common query on this particular table increased over time, at one point to ~130ms which starved the whole instance. The planning time went back to normal after vacuuming and analyzing but is slowly creeping up again. What's particularly strange though is that the planning time seems to depend on the input data:

```
explain analyze select * from django_session where expire_date > now() limit 1;
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=1 width=207) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on django_session  (cost=0.00..6357552.08 rows=129398117 width=207) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (expire_date > now())
 Planning Time: 7.201 ms
 Execution Time: 0.022 ms
```

In contrast to:

```
explain analyze select * from django_session where expire_date > now() + interval '2 days' limit 1;
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=1 width=207) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on django_session  (cost=0.00..6681337.26 rows=128206390 width=207) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (expire_date > (now() + '2 days'::interval))
 Planning Time: 0.053 ms
 Execution Time: 0.020 ms
```

This cut-off of about 2 days between increased and normal planning time exists regardless of what type of comparison is made (i.e. <, >, = all have the same effect).

The table is cleaned up every day by deleting old sessions that are expired.

Given the range of `expiry_date` of up to a year in the future could it be that Postgres' heuristic assumes that an `expiry_date` in the near future is an unlikely input? Why does this only happen when querying for this particular column and none of the others in the same table?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Version of PG? And have you confirmed that the IRL queries also have a `LIMIT 1` (and, for that matter, do they not have a session id or similar in the WHERE?)?

Comment: PostgreSQL is version 11.6.
The IRL queries are of the form `SELECT * FROM "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."expire_date" > '2020-04-22T17:44:32.139601'::timestamp AND "django_session"."session_key" = 'somesessionkey')`; so there's no `LIMIT 1` and they also query the `session_key`. From my tests it does not make a difference whether `LIMIT 1` or any other column is referenced in the `WHERE` clause. Any query with `expiry_date` shows this behaviour. I used `LIMIT 1` in the examples to get something that only uses `expiry_date` and still executes in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: If you switch back and forth between the two queries repeatedly in rapid succession, are the timings shown reproducible?  If you run them without the EXPLAIN, is the measured time taken for each execution consistent with the sum of the two times from the EXPLAIN ANALYZE?

Comment: Yes, the timings are reproducible when running both queries in any order repeatedly. Also, with `\timing on` the run times are consistent with being the the sum of planning and execution time plus some extra overhead (around 0.2 ms for both queries).

Comment: Can you run the slow query in a tight loop (using pgbench with a custom query for example, or maybe psql with `\watch 0.00001`) and then run `perf -p <pid>` on the backend process?  This could quickly confirm Laurenz's theory, or suggest a different one.  You might need to install debug symbols to get usable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is an optimization in PostgreSQL, weird as it sounds.

When estimating result counts ow `WHERE` conditions like the one in your query, PostgreSQL uses a histogram, which is an approximation of the distribution of the values in the column.

Now these histograms are only re-calculated when 10% or more of the table has changed. With data like time-series, that can lead to a considerable skew, because the maximum (or minimum) of the values keeps increasing (or decreasing). So even if only a small percentage of the data change, the minimum or maximum can become inaccurate rather quickly.

To improve estimates, PostgreSQL commit [40608e7f949](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=40608e7f949fb7e4025c0ddd5be01939adc79eec) has added a feature: when the cut-off value is in or beyond the last histogram bucket (as it is in your case), and if there is an index on the column, the optimizer will scan the index for the actual minimum or maximum and use that instead. This improves the quality of the estimate considerably.

However, there is a drawback. If the extreme values of the index all belong to deleted (“dead”) table rows, the index scan has to scan way more entries than it bargained for the get the actual minimum or maximum. This has been improved with commit [3ca930fc39c](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=3ca930fc39ccf987c1c22fd04a1e7463b5dd0dfd) in version 11, which allows such an index scan to “kill” those index tuples, so that the next index scan can quickly ignore them.

I conclude that you must use a version older than v11.

There are two remedies:

1. Upgrade to v11 or better.
2. Set `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor` low (0.01 or lower) for that table, so that it is processed by autovacuum more often. `VACUUM` gets rid of those dead index entries, which will make query planning fast again.

Comment: By V11 do you mean version 11.x? Because we are already using Postgres version 11.6.

Comment: Then - provided my theory is true - there is something like a long running transaction that keeps the index tuples from being killed. Anyway, if `VACUUM` fixes the problem, you can follow that path.

Comment: When a large table is cleaned up of records daily, shouldn't it be vacuum'ed / analyzed on a daily base anyway?

Comment: Regular vacuuming is the first thing we're going to try. The optimizations Laurenz mentioned seem to be a good candidate for what is going on.